# How to resume terminal functionality after issuing the "suspend" command?

Tags: command-line, bash, job-control

I typed [`suspend`](https://ss64.com/bash/suspend.html) in my terminal, and it suspended the execution.

How do I get back to normal terminal functioning? I've tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> ([as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513923/what-is-the-key-combination-to-send-a-sigstop-signal-on-terminal)), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, but none of these work. Of course I can close the terminal and open a new one, but is there no way to "resume" the terminal functionality?

I'm running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, with default (bash) shell.

Comment: Sorry for that I'm asking here, but what is the purpose of this command?

Comment: To stop executing a script and have it continue later ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From your link:

> until it receives a SIGCONT signal.

So that would be `kill -SIGCONT {pid}`

- `killall -CONT bash` would resume all.
- `kill -18 {pid}` would be the same.
- and so is `kill -s CONT {pid}`

---

According to this [list](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317492/list-of-kill-signals) it should be control-z but you need to use control-z to stop the process:

```
18 - SIGCONT - Resume process, ctrl-Z (2nd)
19 - SIGSTOP - Pause the process / free command line, ctrl-Z (1st)
```

---

You need the {pid} of the shell session running in the terminal

---

And there is also [job control commands](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html):

```
fg, bg

The fg command switches a job running in the background into the foreground. 
The bg command restarts a suspended job, and runs it in the background. 
If no job number is specified, then the fg or bg command acts 
upon the currently running job.
```

Comment: It should also be Ctrl+Q, but that isn't working for some reason. I assume because since the shell is suspended, it can't receive the Ctrl+Q (SIGCONT) from the suspended session. It does work if, as you say, you use `kill -SIGCONT PID` but I can't find a simple way of getting the suspended session's PID when I have many terminals open.

Comment: This isn't working. I used ps aux | grep term to get the pid of the the terminal, tried all 3 variations of SIGCONT but none worked.

When I did just kill pid the terminal did close, so I did have the correct pid.

Comment: @Cerberus you want the PID of the shell session running in the terminal, not of the terminal itself. If you only have one open terminal, it should be easy to find with `pgrep bash`. If not, use `pstree -p`, find the terminal's PID there and look at the PIDs of its children, one of which should be your bash session.

Comment: I will need to have two terminal sessions at least in the scenario, one which is suspended and the other from which to send SIGCONT.

Comment: Well yes. If you want to use suspend. Can't really think of why you would want to though.

Comment: @Cerberus yes you need 2 :-)

Comment: I was just wondering how to get back. But thanks, this finally worked. Using pgrep bash and trial and error to identify correct shell session worked out for me.

Comment: SIGCONT is normally ignored, so why not just fire ``killall -CONT bash``? :-)

Comment: @JonasWielicki nice, this is a lot easier and resumes all suspended shell sessions.

Comment: I assumed one pid though and not all. edit: added it :)